# PHPmyadmin mass update

Tags: phpmyadmin

I've tried a number of different ways, nothing has worked yet... need help.

Trying to update column `code` where entries are `Null` within table `media`. Column contains a javascript code and type is set to text.

Also trying to find a way to set default to auto insert the js code when a new entry is added.  Any help or tips would be great!  The issue seems to be problems with the function where the java tags are due to the ticks and backslashes.

Comment: Can you give an example (maybe a reduced one) of your javascript code that you're trying to put in the column?

Comment: Sure- it is an ad code- something like    <script type="text/javascript">
var Opts =
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ads..../invideo.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
    UPDATE `media` SET `code`= '<script type="text/javascript"> var Opts = </script>     <script type="text/javascript" src="ads..../invideo.js"></script>' where `code` is null
```